# URL Rewrite Outbound rule involving flash

Tags: url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I’m having an issue I’m hoping you can help with.  I’m being forced to use the URL Rewrite module on an IIS server to strip a port number out of all of the URL’s being displayed.  Basically, there are some functions on the back end that account for the port number, but having it displayed in the URL breaks stuff.  So in effect, I need to make http://mysever.example.com:8084 show as http://mysever.example.com and the port is cared for behind the scenes.  Since this is NOT my specialty at all, I’ve muddled my way through the use of the tool and it all works great.  That is, except for a single (fairly important) function that I just noticed is not working.  Some of the pages have embedded flash content that shows various data that is reported on.  When those reports should populate, it gives me a blank screen, so I checked the source code on the client and sure enough it’s not removing the port.  Here’s an example of what I’m seeing:

`<div id="flashContent_108">
<img src="http://myserver.example.com/" width="16" height="16" alt="" onload="renderFlash('108','http://myserver.example.com:8084/reports/20180612-083829-107.swf','760','250')" /></div>`

As you can see, it’s rewriting the img src correctly, but then it’s like it just skips the next mention of the url.  Can anyone give me some guidance on how I would correct this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the issue.  I had a type in my outbound rule that I somehow overlooked each of the 100 times I checked it over.